# Will upgrading a smart contract to inherit from a new base class cause potential storage conflicts with UUPS proxy pattern?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I have an ERC20 contract like so:

```
contract myToken is ERC20BurnableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable, PausableUpgradeable

{

    mapping(address => uint256) public totalSpent;
    mapping(address => TotalAllocation) public allocations;
    mapping(address => bool) public isWhitelisted;
    uint256 whitelistAddEnd; //time when you can no longer update the whitelist
    uint256 public deploymentTime;
    address public veTokenMigrator;

    // Reserved storage space to allow for layout changes in the future from upgrading.
    uint256[50] __gap;

    ....events, constructor, functions etc
}
```

If I upgrade this contract to also inherit `ERC20Votes.sol`, will that mess up my contract's current storage configuration?

```
contract myToken is ERC20BurnableUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable, PausableUpgradeable, ERC20Votes 
{
    mapping(address => uint256) public totalSpent;
    ... all the other code from above
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the state variables of the `myToken` contract will occupy new slot positions, following those from `ERC20Votes`. Here are two solutions:

1. Use `@openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\token\ERC20\extensions\ERC20VotesUpgradeable.sol` instead of `ERC20Votes`. The `ERC20VotesUpgradeable` contract has an offset in storage locations for its state variables to avoid conflicts with other inherited contracts.
2. Still possible to solve it with `ERC20Votes`: create the abstract contract named `MyTokenStorage` containing all current state variables, and include it in the inheritance chain before `ERC20Votes`.

```typescript
abstract contract MyTokenStorage {
    mapping(address => uint256) public totalSpent;
    mapping(address => TotalAllocation) public allocations;
    mapping(address => bool) public isWhitelisted;
    uint256 whitelistAddEnd; 
    uint256 public deploymentTime;
    address public veTokenMigrator;

    uint256[50] private __gap;
}

contract MyToken is 
    ERC20BurnableUpgradeable, 
    OwnableUpgradeable, 
    UUPSUpgradeable, 
    PausableUpgradeable,
    MyTokenStorage,
    ERC20Votes {

    // ...events, constructor, functions, etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So to be clear, the solution is to inherit ERC20VotesUpgradeable.sol, and in this case there should be no conflicts?

Comment: Correct, `ERC20VotesUpgradeable` has no state variables, so it won't conflict with `myToken` storage.

Comment: on line 34, 37 and 38 of OpenZeppelin's ERC20VotesUpgradeable there are variables, how are they handled differently?

Comment: @BarneyChambers Where https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20VotesUpgradeable.sol ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it looks like I've imported a much older version of ERC20VotesUpgradeable (pragma 0.8.0 and v4.9.0)